# combine two string word by word in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to combine two sentences word by word in java without using any special string methods except charAt and length.

It's like

```
String s1="hello world";

String s2="programmers are greeting"
```

I want to combine that two string get one word from `s1` then get one word from `s2` and keep until there is no word left in `s1` and `s2` in `s3`.

```
String s3="hello programmers world are greeting"
```

Here's my method but when I run it doesn't return anything. I couldn't find the problem:

```
void combine(String str1, String str2) {
    int i,
    j,
    sl1,
    sl2,
    s,
    test;

    sl1 = str1.length();
    sl2 = str2.length();
    test = sl1 + sl2;
    char[] ar1 = new char[sl1];
    char[] ar2 = new char[sl2];

    for (i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++)
    {
        ar1[i] = str1.charAt(i);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < ar2.length; j++)
    {
        ar2[j] = str2.charAt(j);
    }

    char[] array = new char[test];
    s = array.length;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    while (s <= i + j) {
        while (ar1[i] != ' ')
        {
            if (i == sl1) break;
            array[i + j] = ar1[i];
            i = i + 1;
        }

        while (ar2[j] != ' ')
        {
            if (j == sl2) break;
            array[j + i] = ar2[j];
            j = j + 1;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method's return type is `void`. Change `void` to `String`,  and add a return statement

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: I've fixed the formatting for you, as well as doing the things they taught you in English class, such as capitalizing the word "I", putting in an apostrophe in contractions like "doesn't" and "couldn't", etc.  Please think of SO as an at least semi-professional environment and do those things, and don't use slang like "wanna." Happy coding.

Comment: To return a `String` from your result `char[] array`, you'd have to call `new String(char[])`. Don't know if that's considered a "special" string method. If it is, then maybe using a `StringBuilder` is ok, as it is certainly not a special method of the *`String`* class. If that's "special" too, then string concatenation, using the `+` operator, seems to be the only choice, as that is certainly not a special string method, not being a "method" at all.

Answer (score 1):

The method combine is void which should become `int` otherwise you should output the answer using a `System.out.println();`